# Excel VBA automating

Tags: vba, excel

I'm automating excel using VBA. I have created 2 new columns and one of the columns used to have the vlookup function.Сode works properly however I faced one problem. The quantity of Countries_2018.xlsx file can be changed that is why how can I make it  dynamic? I mean the data of Countries_2018.xlsx grows and shrinks. Can you check and give me idea? Thank you in advance

```
Sub Test() Dim Rng1 As Range Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Columns("B:B").Insert
    Cells(1, 2) = "Íàïðàâëåíèå"
    Columns("S:S").Insert
    Cells(1, 19) = "CDR â ìèíóòàõ"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Rng1 = Range("S2:S" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Rng1.FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-4] / 60"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[Countries_2018.xlsx]Sheet!R1C[-1]:R2588C,2,0)"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share more details for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range

    Columns("B:B").Insert
    Cells(1, 2) = "Íàïðàâëåíèå"
    Columns("S:S").Insert
    Cells(1, 19) = "CDR â ìèíóòàõ"

    Set Rng1 = Range("S2:S" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set Rng2 = Range("B2:B" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)
    Rng1.FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-4] / 60"
    Rng2.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX([Countries_2018.xlsx]Sheet!C2,MATCH(RC1,[Countries_2018.xlsx]Sheet!C1,0))"

End Sub
```